# not boolean value but use ||

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

the below code get the window size in different browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.innerHTML = "Browser inner window width: " + w + ", height: " + h + ".";
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to ask window.innerWidth OR document.documentElement.clientWidth etc.. they are not Boolean values, how can I use || to declare a variable? 
w/h are numbers, it's like if I do the following:

```
var k = aaa || bbb || 45;
```

k is supposed to be a number, this is illegal, right?
How can the first piece of code work then?
Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the concept of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values in Javascript.

`0`, `null` and `undefined` all evaluate to `false` if you use them in a boolean context. So that allows you to make assignments like the above- the value of `var k` will be the first variable that is truthy.

`var k = aaa || bbb || 45;`

If `aaa` is truthy(so, a number, or some defined value), then `k` becomes that, OR it becomes `b` if that is truthy, otherwise it becomes the number `45`.

Comment: Point of note: empty strings are also falsy.

Answer (score 0):

*I realize that you most probably have your answer now, but I am posting an answer anyways because: **a.** the question is important and will surely have a sufficient amount of future viewers. **b.** the other answer does not explain the relationship between `ToBoolean` and `||` very well **c.** I would have to change and add too much if i were to edit the other answer instead, so...*

---

In JavaScript, both the `||` and `&&` logical operators will coerce their operands to `boolean` if they aren't booleans already, using the abstract `ToBoolean` operation.

You can see the effects of this `ToBoolean` operation using the `Boolean` constructor or an implicit `!!` conversion:

```
Boolean(foo);
!!foo;
```

Either of the 2 lines above will convert `foo` to a boolean.

But how do they do it ? 
It's much simple: If the variable `foo` is either `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, or `""` (you could also say `false`, but that's a tad obvious), it will become `false`; in all other cases, it will become `true`.

Values that become `false` after a `ToBoolean` coercion (which can be performed by either of the above lines) are called "falsy values". Can you guess what values which become `true` after a `ToBoolean` operation are called ?

Here is an example of some `ToBoolean` operations:

```js
const foo = "abc";

console.log(!!foo); // Prints out "true"
console.log(Boolean(foo)); // Same thing as above

const bar = "";
const baz = undefined;

console.log(Boolean(bar)); // Prints out "false"
console.log(Boolean(baz)); // Prints out "false"

/* Prints out "abc", because both "bar" and "baz" will become "false" after "||" coerces them to "boolean"*/
console.log(bar || baz || foo);
```

So, in your example, if `aaa` is either of the "falsy" values I listed above, JavaScript will skip it and go to the next operand of `||`, if that operand is not a falsy value, it will be selected by `||`.

As a sidenote, `||` will always stop at the first "truthy" value, if there are no truthy values, it will select the last operand.

---

[Here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean) is a link to `ToBoolean` in the specs.