# Comparing arrays in javascript where order doesn't matter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning Javascript, and I saw a function on SO for comparing arrays to check if they are same. However, my current function returns false if the two arrays are [string1,string2] & [string2,string1]. Basically, the two positions are interchanged. The code is as follows:

```
function _compareArrays(arr1,arr2){
    var result = arr1 != null && arr2 != null && arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.every(function(element) {
            return arr2.indexOf(element);
        });
    return result ;
}
```

However, I want these two arrays to be returned as same. So, I changed `.every` to `.indexOf()` and it seemed to work. But, I have a doubt, how exactly is the counter getting incremented here to make sure the comparison is being done for every element?
I mean, like, in C++, we do,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]
      cout<<"Elements are same\n";
```

Here, I have an explicit `i++` which increments the counter. How does it happen in the above function?

Thanks!

Comment: your first code block is total rubbish. `indexOf` does not take a function as an argument in any documentation I've ever read - `So, I changed .every to .indexOf()` when you have a flat tyre, do you replace the wheel with a banana?

Comment: I'd just [create shallow copies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978492/javascript-fastest-way-to-duplicate-an-array-slice-vs-for-loop) of the arrays, sort those and then use the comparison mechanism you mentioned

Comment: The `_compareArrays` method you've defined always returns -1. 

As for how the `every` method iterates without explicitly incrementing a counter: It's a function on the Array prototype that does the itteration automatically. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: See my edited function, will the above function also not work?

Comment: @sarah See my answer again.

Comment: for a lowdash version - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951293/using-lodash-to-compare-arrays-items-existence-without-order

Answer (score 2):

Convert the array into an object instead. Convert array values into keys and their respective count as their value. This is more performant as you iterate over the arrays only once.

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }
  let set = {};
  a.forEach((i) => {
    if (set[i] !== undefined) {
      set[i]++;
    } else {
      set[i] = 1;
    }
  });
  let difference = b.every((i) => {
    if (set[i] === undefined) {
      return false;
    } else {
      set[i]--;
      if (set[i] === 0) {
        delete set[i];
      }
      return true;
    }
  });
  return Object.keys(set) == 0 && difference;
}
```

The first loop on the first array initialises the the set (object), the second loop on the second array subtracts the count and removes the keys when the count hits 0. If a key is not found or if the set is not empty at the end of the procedure, then the arrays are not similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your current has these issues:

1. It will return `true` for these 2 arrays (I hope that you understand that this is not specific to these 2): `[1, 2, 2]`, `[1,1,2]`. This problem is why I set indices to `undefined` after a match in my solution below.
2. `indexOf` returns `-1` for element's it cannot find, and any number `>= 0` if it can find the element, `-1` is truthy, so if an element cannot be found, your comparison will return `true`, and `0` is falsy, so if an element is located in the first index of the second array, your method will return `false` (which means the whole thing will become `false`, because of `every`...). So, you should add a `~` before the result of `indexOf` call: `~arr2.indexOf(element)`.

   See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT)
   MDN page on the Bitwise Not operator (`~`) and how it solves the
   `indexOf` problem I mentioned.

   I also recommend that you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666481/5451765) answer of mine on truthy/falsy values and how they interact with `&&` and `||`.

---

So Try this out (it's mostly your example, except there is no `indexOf` used and I have fixed problem #2):

```js
function _compareArrays(arr1,arr2){
  if(!(arr1 != null && arr2 != null && arr1.length == arr2.length)) {
    return false;
  }

  /* copy the arrays so that the original arrays are not affected when we set the indices to "undefined" */
  arr1 = [].concat(arr1);
  arr2 = [].concat(arr2);

  return arr1.every(function(element, index) {
    return arr2.some(function(e, i) {
      return e === element && (arr2[i] = undefined, true);
    });
  });
}
    
var x = ["str", "boo", "str"];
var y = ["boo", "str", "str"];
var z = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]    

console.log(_compareArrays(x, y));
console.log(_compareArrays(x, z));
console.log(_compareArrays(z, z));
```

It won't work if the array has any `undefined` elements, though.

Comment: Why would you change the values of the array? I would like to have the values retained.

Comment: You could set all undefined values to null at the start of the function. But that would be a bit janky solution.

Comment: @sarah Otherwise, [1, 2, 1] would be marked as equal to [1, 2, 2]

Comment: @nipuna777 I am sure there is a solution for this problem, perhaps I could find it, but I am going to school right now.

Comment: @nipuna777, I tried sorting the arrays before comparing. But that didn't work either. Why do you think that will happen?

Comment: @sarah The arrays won't be changed now

Answer (score 1):

So the fastest way would be to sort both arrays, then compare each one element by element. This requires `2n * log(n) + n` time rather than n<sup>2</sup> time.

```
function compareArrays(arr1, arr2){
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

  // implement custom sort if necessary
  arr1.sort();
  arr2.sort();

  // use normal for loop so we can return immediately if not equal
  for(let i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```